# MySQL: Howto select certain rows of a table and do SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: mysql, string

I'm not finding the right answer and getting more an more confused about a very simple task.

What words I have:

```
sun
fun
dark
light
clunch
cruca
suda
muda
```

What **result** I want to get:

```
un
unch
uca
uda
```

And where I'am at the moment:

```
 sun
 fun
 null
 null
 clunch
 cruca
 suda
 muda
```

My very simple beginner code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP '[u]{1}[a-tv-z]{1,3}$';
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(??????,'a',-1);
```

I understand that I can pass just a single value to the function. I have  experimented with creating a temporary table but I'm really stucked.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (SELECT * FROM table WHERE title REGEXP '[u]{1}[a-tv-z]{1,3}$')
```

Could you please give me a small hint how I can do several commands in a row and pass the results from one step to another? Also I want to have the unique endings of the words and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I have tested this: SELECT SUBSTR(title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, "u", -1)) FROM page WHERE title REGEXP '[u]{1}[a-tv-z]{1,3}$'; but it just gives me an *empty* result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick! Thank your for yur guidance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(
SUBSTR(title, - 5 + LOCATE('u', SUBSTR(title, - 4))))
FROM table WHERE title REGEXP '[u]{1}[a-tv-z]{1,3}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to do two things here:

1. Only select the rows which contain 'un'
2. From **those rows**, only select the text beginning 'un' onwards

To achieve the first part on its own, you use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%un%'
```

That will give you

```
sun
fun
clunch
```

But that's `SELECT`ing the entire `title` - you just want the part beginning with 'un' onwards. So you now change what you `SELECT`. You need the substring that starts from the location of your 'un'. Something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(title, LOCATE(title, "un")) FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%un%'
```

And now you'll see

```
un
un
unch
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it's my fault I have not given you the full details of this example. I have updated my question. The example is a bit more complex and I need to use REGEXP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using LIKE as a filter:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(title, LOCATE(title, "un")) FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%un%';
```

If you MUST use SUBSTR_INDEX, try this (assuming the substring "un" is only present once)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(title, SUBSTR_INDEX(title, "un", -1)) FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%un%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it's my fault I have not given you the full details of this example. I have updated my question. The example is a bit more complex and I need to use REGEXP.